# Is $\{ ab \}_{b=1}^{\infty}$ closed in $\mathbb{N}$ for a positive integer $a$? or is it only closed when $a$ is a prime number?

Tags: general-topology

[[image: I just used <span class=]$ab$ instead of $np$." />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwZAL.png)

Sorry for the confusion, I inserted the photo because it is very similar. But to clarify, the main differences between my problem and the one in the photo are: 1. I have $ab$ instead of $np$. 2. In my problem, it is not stated that $(a,k) = 1$ in $\{ ab+k\}$.

**And my main question is**: Is it also true for positive integers $a$ or is it only closed when $a$ is a prime.

the complement is $ \{ab + 1 \}_{b=1}^{\infty} \bigcup \{ab + 2 \}_{b=1}^{\infty} \bigcup \dots \bigcup  \{ab + (a-1) \}_{b=1}^{\infty}$ which is a union of open sets (I can't prove either how each of these are open while {ab } is closed). Since the complement is a union of open sets, then it must be closed.

Comment: anyone? or is this a stupid question?

Comment: The set is closed when $a=1$ (the complement is empty and thus open), so *not* only when $a$ is prime. I don't think it's closed for other non-prime $a$ but I don't have a proof.

Comment: Thank you! but in my problem, it is not specified that $(a,k)=1$ in $\{ab+k\}$. does that still apply?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I inserted the photo because it is very similar. But to clarify, the main differences between my problem and the one in the photo are: 1. I have $ab$ instead of $np$. 2. In my problem, it is not stated that $(a,k) = 1$ in $\{ ab+k\}$.  **And my main question is**: Is it also true for positive integers $a$ or is it only closed when $a$ is a prime.

Comment: @ThomasLumley ...

Answer (score 0):

By definition, if $(a,b)=1$, then the set of the form $\{an+b\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is an open set, because it is an element of the basis of open sets.

Now, we also know that if $p$ is prime, then $(p, 1)=(p,2)=(p,3)=\cdots = (p, p-1) = 1$.

This means that:

- Because $(p,1)=1$, we know that $\{pn + 1\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is open
- Because $(p,2)=1$, we know that $\{pn + 2\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is open
- Because $(p,3)=1$, we know that $\{pn + 3\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is open
- $\vdots$
- Because $(p,p-1)=1$, we know that $\{pn + p-1\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is open

Since we also know that a union of open sets is open, that means that

$$\{np+1\}_{n=1}^\infty \cup \{np+2\}_{n=1}^\infty\cup\{np+3\}_{n=1}^\infty\cup\cdots\cup\{np+p-1\}_{n=1}^\infty$$

is also an open set.

Comment: Thank you! but in my problem, it is not specified that $(a,k)=1$ in $\{ab+k\}$. does that still apply?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I inserted the photo because it is very similar. But to clarify, the main differences between my problem and the one in the photo are: 1. I have $ab$ instead of $np$. 2. In my problem, it is not stated that $(a,k)=1$ in $\{ab+k\}$. **And my main question is**: Is it also true for positive integers $a$ or is it only closed when $a$ is a prime number.